# UnityWebRequest HTTP POST to Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, http-post, webrequest, google-cloud-functions

I'm Having some trouble making an POST Http Request to my firebase cloud-functions project from Unity3D game engine.

I keep getting a code 400 response, and in the firebase console I can see the following error:

> Error: invalid json at parse

I don't really have a lot of knowledge about Http requests, and after quite some time of trying to find out a solution I'd like to ask for help.

Here is the client code:

```
public void RateLevel(string guid, int rating)
{
    RateLevelRequest rlr = new RateLevelRequest (guid, rating.ToString());
    string body = rlr.ToJson ();
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("myurl", body);
    www.SetRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
    StartCoroutine (MakeRequest (www));
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
 * AUXILIAR CLASS FOR HTTP REQUESTS  *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

[System.Serializable]
public class RateLevelRequest
{
    public string guid;
    public string rating;

    public RateLevelRequest(string _guid, string _rating)
    {
        guid = _guid;
        rating = _rating;
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson (this);
        Debug.Log ("RateLevelRequest Json: " + json);
        return json;
    }
}
```

I can guarantee that the json is well formed, with values like this.

> {"guid":"fake-guid","rating":"-1"}

And here is my current deployed function in firebase-functions.

```
exports.rate_level = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if(req.method === 'POST')
    {
        console.log('guid: ' + req.body.guid);
        console.log('rating: ' + req.body.rating);
        console.log('invented var: ' + req.body.myinvention);

        if(req.body.guid && req.body.rating &&
        (req.body.rating == 1 || req.body.rating == -1))
        {
            res.status(200).send('You are doing a post request with the right fields and values');
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(403).send('Required Fields are not Defined!')
        }
    }
    else
    {
        res.status(403).send('Wrong Request Method!');
    }
});
```

Has anyone tried this and succeeded before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the answer in an [excellent blog entry](https://codetolight.wordpress.com/2017/01/18/unity-rest-api-interaction-with-unitywebrequest-and-besthttp/).

I really don't know what was wrong, but I instead replaced my code to the one indicated in the article mentioned above, which works. I'll post it for the rest of you having issues.

```
    public void RateLevel(string guid, int rating)
    {
        RateLevelRequest rlr = new RateLevelRequest (guid, rating.ToString());
        string body = rlr.ToJson ();
        byte[] bodyRaw = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding ().GetBytes (body);
        UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest("myurl", UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST);
        www.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw (bodyRaw);
        www.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        www.SetRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
        StartCoroutine (MakeRequest (www));
    }
```

Best!